# Simple QML with qmlscene on Bash on Windows causes a segfault

Tags: qt, ubuntu, opengl, qml, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use QML on Bash on Windows. However, this very simple QML code with `qmlscene` causes a segmentation fault.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    width:  100
    height: 100
}
```

With gdb, I got this backtrace.

```
#0  __strstr_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strstr-sse2-unaligned.S:40
#1  0x00007f9cf6e5e5a5 in strstr (__needle=<optimized out>, __haystack=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/string.h:337
#2  QGLXContext::queryDummyContext () at qglxintegration.cpp:466
#3  0x00007f9cf6e5e6e1 in QGLXContext::supportsThreading () at qglxintegration.cpp:488
#4  0x00007f9d001bf938 in QSGRenderLoop::instance () at scenegraph/qsgrenderloop.cpp:169
#5  0x00007f9d001df6af in QQuickWindowPrivate::init (this=0x1538ea0, c=0x13faf20) at items/qquickwindow.cpp:417
#6  0x00007f9d0027dca6 in QQuickView::QQuickView (this=0x13faf20, engine=0x7fffee8d4d50, parent=0x0) at items/qquickview.cpp:193
#7  0x00000000004054df in main (argc=1, argv=<optimized out>) at main.cpp:496
```

I wonder that the current version of BoW has not yet allowed us to use QML applications but I would be glad if I can.

`xeyes` and `glxgears` run fine and other Qt5 applications such as QGo also seem so.

My environment is shown below:

- Windows 10 Version 1607 and OS Build 14393.321
- Ubuntu 14.04
- VcXsrv 1.18.3.0 as a X server with `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1`
- Qt 5.2.1

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

---

Addition (reply to @Mitch):

I ran the above QML with `$ env QSG_INFO=1 qmlscene simple.qml` but qmlscene outputted only `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I also executed qmlscene with no argument, `$ env QSG_INFO=1 qmlscene` and then qmlscene outputted these lines and made a file dialog:

```
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: Invalid argument
QXcbShmImage: shmget() failed (38) for size 1023360 (624x410)
QXcbXSettings::QXcbXSettings(QXcbScreen*) Failed to get selection owner for XSETTINGS_S atom
```

After I chose `simple.qml` on the dialog, qmlscene terminated, outputting only `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` too.

Instead, When I executed `$ env LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose qmlscene simple.qml`, I got these lines:

```
function is no-op
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

Addition 2:

I found that `glGetString` returns null in `QGLXContext::queryDummyContext`. This causes a segfault. [This bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48986) might be related to this problem but I'm not sure about the details.

With glut, `glGetString` behaves ordinarily.

Comment: Can you please run your application with `QSG_INFO=1` and include the output in your question?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Qt?

Comment: @Frank-Meerkötter Because the current version of BoW provides Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 provides Qt 5.2.1. (I'm waiting the next update of Windows brings us Ubuntu 16.04, with Qt 5.5.1.)

Comment: Eh, I don't know what's going on with the environment variable... I'd usually just run e.g. `QSG_INFO=1 qmlscene simple.qml` and it'd work. I'm pretty sure `QSG_INFO` existed in Qt 5.2. You can also try `QSG_RENDER_LOOP=basic`, but I'm just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: @Mitch I tried both (and QSG_RENDER_LOOP=window etc), but nothing changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that WSL in Windows 10 Anniversary Update (14393) doesn't support INOTIFY. [INOTIFY support arrived in Insiders build 14942](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/07/wsl-adds-inotify-filesystem-change-notification-support/).

> Note: If you do find issues in WSL, please file a bug in [our GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/) where WSL engineers & our community hang out & offer support and request further details to help fix.

Thanks.